# Android SlidingPaneLayout fades wrong views

Tags: android, xml, view, fade, slidingpanelayout

I'm using a SlidingPaneLayout in my app and I have a problem because when I open the sliding pane, the whole covered pane doesn't fade, instead only some elements inside of it do, like TextViews, Buttons, and ImageViews. How can I either remove the fading completely or make the whole covered pane to fade out?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272856/slidingpanelayout-setcoveredfadecolor-and-setsliderfadecolor Seems to answer what you're asking to an extent (to remove the fading at least)

Comment: yep i've seen this already, and it doesn't help, transparent is default and it fades a bit into grey still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just recently figured it out, when I changed the default background of the whole layout it fades properly the whole fragment.

Comment: please close this question if you have the awnser

Answer (score 1):

You can set the fade color to transparent:

> SlidingPaneLayout sp = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainSlider);
>   sp.setSliderFadeColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

Hope this will help.